# Rails spends 2~3 seconds before processing request. How to resolve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have a Rails app, and it seems that every request cost it 2~3 seconds before processed.

e.g. when I start a GET request, which real time is x ms.  However it takes me 3 seconds in total, I found that in the log file, Rails would stop 2~3 seconds between `Started GET...` and `Processing by...` :

```
Started GET "/api/users/me" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-05-29 16:14:15 +0900

[ 2~3 seconds waiting....]

Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#me as */*
  Mother::User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1647], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:75:in `get_current_operator'
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 0.2ms | Allocations: 667)
```

my environment:

- Rails 6 , development mode   ( run in docker )
- Windows 10, docker desktop 4.8.1 , WSL 2
- database: postgres 10.14  ( run in docker )
- Rails route:  400+
- hardware: CPU 16core 32thread, 128G memo.   CPU usage: 1%~5%, mem usage: <= 50G

I have written Rails for 10+ years, so, any ideas? thanks !

Comment: Is there any `sleep` in your controllers? Maybe someone added that on ApplicationController.

Comment: @Christos-AngelosVasilopoulos thanks for reply, however I checked the ApplicationController very carefully, no such `sleep` statement.  I think the root cause maybe I am using Win10, but not Linux.

Comment: @Siwei try to profile your application, for example, using this: https://stackify.com/rack-mini-profiler-a-complete-guide-on-rails-performance/

Comment: If the delay does not cause 100% CPU usage, then often hangups like this can be caused by DNS lookups in the application. I.e. you have a client with IP 11.22.33.44 come in, and somewhere the app tries to figure out the hostname for 11.22.33.44. If the DNS resolver for your Docker image is not set up properly, the DNS lookup may hang until it is timed out. This is what causes the 2-3 sleep. Note: check CPU usage first. If 2-3s is spent just idling, it is much more likely the problem is related to a resource timeout issue, like DNS lookup.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Rails 3 app running on Docker and WSL2. The app performs well when I run the docker container on a Linux machine.

Comment: @Casper thanks for reply, I have a 32thread AMD 7302 CPU, usage 1%~5%, memory 128G 3200 Mhz in total, and used less than 50G.  DNS is less than 1 ms.

Comment: @emilianolch  yes, the same!!!  in my old Linux laptop, there's no 2~3 seconds delay at all. performs very well,